# Syntax error: Expected end of input but got identifier

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to run the following query but keep getting the same error

> Syntax error: Expected end of input but got identifier "BD_Dictionary"
> at [3:1]

My query is:

```
SELECT
MI.* except(period_date, entity_level, email_access, period_filter)
BD_Dictionary.BD_EMAIL, BD_Dictionary.AREA_LEAD, BD_Dictionary.BD_LEADER
FROM
  `mi-trial-365509.Trial.MI` as MI
INNER JOIN
  `mi-trial-365509.Trial.BD Dictionary` as BD_Dictionary
ON
A.bd_email = BD_Dictionary.BD_EMAIL
LIMIT
  1000
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry my bad, i forgot to put a comma in between the table source in SELECT command.

my code is now like this:

```
SELECT
MI.* except(period_date, entity_level, email_access, period_filter),
BD_Dictionary.BD_EMAIL, BD_Dictionary.AREA_LEAD, BD_Dictionary.BD_LEADER
FROM
  `mi-trial-365509.Trial.MI` as MI
INNER JOIN
  `mi-trial-365509.Trial.BD Dictionary` as BD_Dictionary
ON
MI.bd_email = BD_Dictionary.BD_EMAIL
LIMIT
  1000
```